# Invisible ImageView not responding to clicks - How to fix?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-imageview, android-view

I am having some issues creating an invisible ImageView with an onTouch/onClick listener in my Android app.

The issue is that when the ImageView is set to invisable the clicks do not register (the listener is not triggered).

I have tried to force the width and height of the view to be a specific number, thinking that in wrap mode an invisible view might take up no space. I have also tried to set clickable to true and the same for focusable. 
None of these made a differece.

When visible it works fine.

I want an invisible ImageView that will react to clicks/touches. 
How can I fix this?

This is some code from a dummy app that recreates the issue:

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.david.imageviewclicktest.MainActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/test"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_width="500dp"
        android:src="@drawable/listeners"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"></ImageView>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Code:

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        ImageView test = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.test);
        test.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "clicked",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Instead of making it invisible make the alpha channel 0.0f, i.e. make it transparent.

```
android:alpha="0"
```

Or by code

```
imageView.setAlpha(0.0f);
```

Comment: Forgot to mention it but I have also tried that. The issue is that it messes with the color values of the drawable which I need unchanged to filter clicks based on location on the image.

Comment: Couldn't get it. What drawable? Where is that drawable attached to?

Comment: The image in the ImageView is defined through a drawable (png resource file). On it are various colors in various locations. When clicked I check what the background color is and react accordingly. In the case of the code in the question the drawable is "listeners" under the src tag in the XML.

Comment: Then in what case do you want the `ImageView` to get invisible? It would mean that the drawable will also get invisible. Can't get your question, your use case.

Comment: It should always be invisble. the imageview serves as an overlay of a another image. That way when part of the other image is "clicked" the click is in fact on the invisible layer. But even without the underlining picture I cannot get this invisible view to react to a click.

Comment: Then declare a `FrameLayout` with first child of `ImageView` and an ordinary `View` on top of it (which would serve you as an overlay). In that case you will set click listener on the overlay view, thus you won't need to do that weird trick (I'm not sure you can succeed what you are trying to do that way).